# Poor performance of the excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

I made a macro in vb for excel and its working but the problem is that for 40000 rows it works very slow (about 2 min on c2d e7500@2,9 GHz). I think that it can be done faster but I don't know how:) Someone help me?

```
Dim bufor As String
Dim condition As Boolean

    Cells.Find(What:="Month", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.Select

    Do While condition = False
    bufor = Right(ActiveCell.Value, 1)


        If bufor = "1" Then
        ActiveCell.Value = "January"
        ElseIf bufor = "2" Then
        ActiveCell.Value = "February"
        ElseIf bufor = "3" Then
        ActiveCell.Value = "March"
        ElseIf bufor = "4" Then
        ActiveCell.Value = "April"
        ElseIf bufor = "5" Then
        ActiveCell.Value = "May"
        ElseIf bufor = "6" Then
        ActiveCell.Value = "June"
        ElseIf bufor = "7" Then
        ActiveCell.Value = "July"
        ElseIf bufor = "8" Then
       ActiveCell.Value = "August"
       ElseIf bufor = "9" Then
       ActiveCell.Value = "September"
       ElseIf bufor = "10" Then
       ActiveCell.Value = "October"
       ElseIf bufor = "11" Then
       ActiveCell.Value = "November"
     ElseIf bufor = "12" Then
     ActiveCell.Value = "December"
    End If



     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
     ActiveCell.Select


    If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then 
    condition = True
    End If

    Loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code at the start of your macro

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

and at the end of your code don't forget to enable it

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

like

```
sub Test()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 ---- your code------

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: From 12 minutes to 1 minute with this code :D Thank you very much:)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array:

```
Dim bufor                 As Long
Dim rHeader               As Range
Dim vData
Dim lColumn               As Long
Dim startRow              As Long
Dim endRow                As Long
Dim n                     As Long

Set rHeader = Cells.Find(What:="Month", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
                         xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
            , SearchFormat:=False)

If Not rHeader Is Nothing Then
    lColumn = rHeader.Column
    startRow = rHeader.Row + 1
    endRow = Cells(Rows.Count, lColumn).End(xlUp).Row
    vData = Range(.Cells(startRow, lColumn, endRow, lColumn)).Value2

    For n = LBound(vData, 1) To UBound(vData, 1)
        bufor = CLng(Val(Right$(vData(n, 1), 1)))
        Select Case bufor
            Case 1 To 12
                vData(n, 1) = MonthName(bufor)
        End Select
    Next n

    Range(.Cells(startRow, lColumn, endRow, lColumn)).Value2 = vData
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need some time to understand how it works because it seems advanced for me and i don't want to use code which i do not understand. I will analise this exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Getting rid of the selects will speed it up as well.

Also, your macro is not working correctly for the months of October, November, and December since your Right command is only extracting one character.

```
Dim tmpCell As Range 

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 

Set tmpCell = Cells.Find(What:="Month", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _ 
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _ 
    , SearchFormat:=False).Offset(1, 0) 

Do While tmpCell.Value <> "" 
    tmpCell.Value = MonthName(Right(tmpCell.Value, 1)) 
    Set tmpCell = tmpCell.Offset(1, 0) 
Loop 

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 0):

So the final, fastest and correct version: (The same computer 150k rows in 6s)

```
Sub edycja_miesiecy()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 

Dim tmpCell As Range

Set tmpCell = Cells.Find(What:="Month", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Offset(1, 0)

Do While tmpCell.Value <> ""
    tmpCell.Value = month_name(tmpCell.Value)
    Set tmpCell = tmpCell.Offset(1, 0)
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Public Function month_name(bufor As String) As String

        If Left(Right(bufor, 2), 1) = "m" Then
        bufor = Right(bufor, 1)
        Else
        bufor = Right(bufor, 2)
        End If


            If bufor = "1" Then
            month_name = "January"
            ElseIf bufor = "2" Then
            month_name = "February"
            ElseIf bufor = "3" Then
            month_name = "March"
            ElseIf bufor = "4" Then
            month_name = "April"
            ElseIf bufor = "5" Then
            month_name = "May"
            ElseIf bufor = "6" Then
            month_name = "June"
            ElseIf bufor = "7" Then
            month_name = "July"
            ElseIf bufor = "8" Then
           month_name = "August"
           ElseIf bufor = "9" Then
           month_name = "September"
           ElseIf bufor = "10" Then
           month_name = "October"
           ElseIf bufor = "11" Then
           month_name = "November"
           ElseIf bufor = "12" Then
           month_name = "December"
           Else
           month_name = "#Error."
           End If

End Function
```